# AirPods Max not charging from a 5W charger

Tags: charging, power, airpods

I have a 5W charger that I bought from Apple, it works fine with my phone. Now I got AirPods Max, they were delivered with an empty battery, so I started charging them. The headphones immediately woke with 1% of charge and I was able to use them while they were connected. Then I left them for a couple of hours and was surprised to see that they're still at 1%. But the battery *is* charging with a random 13W charger (wire is the same).

Any ideas why that might be the case? I contacted Apple support and the agent was pretty much saying that "chargers might work differently with different devices" and suggested to go to the store and talk to people there when I started pushing the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I have had 2 pairs of AirPods Max that had a short circuit in the logic board and I luckily got them replaced by warranty, both were charged with a 5W power adapter from Apple. Now this is my third pair and I have only been charging it with a brand new 20W power adapter from Apple and the cable included in the box and so far everything is working normally. Apparently, AirPods Max are very sensitive to charging with a power adapter that was not intended. AKA anything but that 20W adapter.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/325491)